# How to call function with infinite-loop?

Tags: c, infinite-loop

I need help to clear my concepts.
I have a function which toggle the Led status on/off after every second. Now the code for the on/off runs inside infite loop.

**Example:**

```
  void ToggleLed( int pin_number)     
  {      
      // some code  
      while(1)    
      {    
          // code to execute the Led status    
      }   
  }
```

Now when I integrate this code with base line and called that function inside other function it just doesnt work no other functionality of software works.

**Question:** Function has infinite-loop and that it doesn't come out of control and other functions called after that function doesn't work.
If that is the case do I need to provide separate thread to it?

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: right, if you want your app to be responsible while using infinite loop you should use separate thread for that loop code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David mentioned, you should run your LED code in a separate thread. http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html#BASICS

Once you have threads, if you want your code to be able to stop your LED from blinking, then add a flag that's checked inside the while loop at each iteration, and if it's set then break out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void * toggle_led(void *ptr);
int stop=0;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");

    // set up thread
    pthread_t LED_thread;
    char * message = "blink!";
    pthread_create( &LED_thread, NULL, toggle_led, (void*) message);

    // do some other work
    sleep(5);

    // ok you want to quit now
    stop=1;
    pthread_join(LED_thread, NULL);
    printf("Goodbye!\n");
    return 0;
}

void *toggle_led(void *ptr)
{
    while (!stop)
    {
        printf("%s \n", (char *)ptr);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: my aim is to toggle the Led as far as software is running. if for some reason software has stopped running then  stop the Led toggle. I am wondering is there is any other way I can do that without using multi threading

Comment: @samantha If you app has a regular pulse then you can but threads are the best solution

Comment: @David, I am  playing with FTDI chips. So I guess there is definitely a pulse which sends high /low signal ? am i right?

Comment: If you take a look at the first example in the link, you'll see that it's pretty simple to implement what you need as a thread

Comment: Hi mikhail, thanks for providing  sample code. I guess my software is working but I am still confused why you have prefered pthread_join instead of pthread_exit().? Thanks

Comment: The `pthread_join()` will allow the main thread to wait for the LED thread and give it a chance to stop blinking and clean up after itself. I could have put a `pthread_exit(ptr)` at the end of `loggle_led()`, but that doesn't seem necessary in this case. The tutorial in the link I provided states: _Threads terminate by explicitly calling pthread_exit, by letting the function return, or by a call to the function exit which will terminate the process including any threads._

Answer (score 2):

Yes you will need a separate thread, or some other form of asynchronous execution. Once you enter that while loop, no other code runs in that thread. Ever.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correcctly nothing works in your integrated version. In that case, yes you probably need to run the infinite loop on a separate thread, because your function with the infinit loop will never exit, so no other code will ever run on that thread.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what OS, but yes, set it as a low-priority thread, minimal stack size.  I flash a LED in my projects, just so I can easily see if the code has reached the abort-handler yet :)

```
void LEDflash_task_code(void *p)
{  
  while (1)
    {  
      FIO1CLR=STATUS_LED;
      OSsleep(750);
      FIO1SET=STATUS_LED;
      OSsleep(250);
    };  
};
```

Comment: the OS is fedora 12 and I am trying to configure the GPIO of FTDI chip.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to hardware peripheral timers (any micrcontroller/microprocessor application), you should use those hardware timers, not threads nor software sleep().

```
void init_toggle_led (uint32_t interval)
{
  setup_hardware_timer(interval);
}

void toggle_led (void)
{
  if( (hardware_timer_register & flag) > 0 )
  {
    port = port ^ pin_mask; 
  }
}

main()
{
  init_toggle_led(1000);

  for(;;)
  {
    do_stuff();
    toggle_led();
  }
}
```

This was an example with polling. Alternatively, you can use hardware interrupts from the timers and toggle the port from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement as a watchdog functionality. Because if you use threads then even if other threads has some issues(like deadlock), your LEDs will toggle as long as `toggle_led` thread works. You need to implement an `toggle_led()` function and call from each of other threads /functions before returning to make sure all other threads/functions are getting executed successfully without waiting continuously for some resources

Comment: @ Mark,  I guess this is what I am looking for. Could you please elaborate on how would I check if all or any of software functionalities are working . If any of functionalities are working I need to send signal to turn on Led.

Comment: @Mark, could you please provide me a hint how to implement watchdog. I am trying to configure FTDI chip.

Comment: I'm not sure. I only edited the answer for formatting purposes to make it more readable. You would need to rely on Srinivas Paluru to respond in this case.